# Stored procedure SQL Server parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure for the following SQL Server table:

```
No    Date          Days       Percentage
 1    17-Aug-12      2          -0.34%
 2    3-Aug-12       15         -29.39%
 3    27-Jul-12      22          12.02%
 4    20-Jul-12      29         -0.64%
 5    13-Jul-12      36         -3.45%
 6    6-Jul-12       43         -99.93%
 7    29-Jun-12      50          41.26%
```

Here I want to pass parameter to the percentage column or the days column dynamically.

Please help wite a stored procedure to select only percentages in a range say ‘12% - 15%’

Comment: What do you mean by "or any other column"? Are you asking for a way to pass in a parameter to state *which* column it to be checked against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply check against percentage...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetPercentages]
( @Low INT, @High INT )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE [Percentage] BETWEEN @Low AND @High
END
```

For more complex checking (where the table and/or fields are specified dynamically) then you could be looking at building a TSQL string to be run against `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters like minvalue and maxvalue as two different parameter and then use them into your SP.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name 
           FROM sys.procedures 
           WHERE name = N'myspSelectDateRange') 
DROP PROCEDURE myspSelectDateRange;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE myspSelectDateRange @DateA DATETIME, @DateB DATETIME 
AS
SELECT [SeqNo], [MyDate], [Days], [Percentage] 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [MyDate] 
BETWEEN @DateA AND @DateB;
GO
```

I hope this helps.